# QEMU riscv32 virt machine, how to access the screen?

Tags: qemu, vga, riscv32

I want to use QEMU to setup a bare metal riscv32 machine and so assume I need to use the '-machine virt' option. How do I setup so I can output to a screen? Either a console style output where I provide strings to be output, or a VGA device where I set memory addresses to cause the output to be defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use uart device to output to the host console. You can check the device mmio base address in hw/riscv/virt.cc

I don’t think qemu riscv virt implemented a vga device.

As it defines PCIe and virtio, I suppose you could dynamically add PCIe video device or virtio device accordingly.